# C++: How to compute hash value from several hashable members?

Tags: c++, hash, hashcode

Suppose I have a C++ class

```
class T {
  Type1 member1;
  Type2 member2;
  Type3 member3;
  unsigned long hash() {
    // How to implement?
  }
};
```

Assuming each member hash a hash function `member.hash()`. What is the best way to implement the `hash` function of class `T`? Java has a `HashCodeBuilder` class specific for this task, is there a counterpart in C++?

I know one possible solution could be something like

```
member1.hash() + member2.hash() * 17 + member3.hash() * 37
```

Is this generally a good hash function?  And how should I choose the constants 17, 37, etc., esp. if I more than 3 members?

Another minor question is assuming one of my member is primitive type (`int`, `float`, `string`, etc.), how should I generate a hash value from it?

Comment: As a third alternative, you can construct the bitwise representaion of your three types and then use the overload of `std::hash` for `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`. This, however, probably yields a much slower performance as compared to the other suggestions which only apply some bitwise operations.

Comment: @davidhigh It's also unlikely to work for a lot of object types.  A bitwise representation is _not_ the object's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost has something for this: [hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html)

```
size_t seed = 0;
boost::hash_combine(seed, member1);
boost::hash_combine(seed, member2);
boost::hash_combine(seed, member3);
return seed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use unordered containers from `std` you may consider the way as given on example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

```
std::size_t operator()(S const& s) const 
{
    std::size_t h1 = std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name);
    std::size_t h2 = std::hash<std::string>()(s.last_name);
    return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
}
```

Comment: Not sure that that's a particularly good solution, as it looses some bits.  I'd generally use something like `return 127 * h1 + h2;`, although other algorithms also work.